# Optimize a classification algorithm using mean per-class accuracy

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, accuracy, scoring-rules

I have a binary classification problem and am trying to find a way to optimize my machine learning algorithm using a performance metric based on the per-class error rate. If I'm not misinterpreting anything, frequently used measures such as sensitivity and specificity focus on one of the two columns in the confusion matrix (optimizing for the rate of true "positives" or false "negatives", if you will), but what I'm looking for is a performance metric that doesn't care about "positives" and "negatives" but simply about the ability of the algorithm to correctly identify any data point as belonging to class 1 or class 2.

I'm being deliberately vague in the description above since I'm having a hard time finding anything useful on this using my (admittedly newbie-ish) Google-fu. Are there any strong theoretical reasons not to use this kind of heuristic to optimize a classification algorithm, or is it just that I'm using the wrong terminology when searching for this?

To be more specific, I'm trying to train a GLM in R using the `caret` package and want to construct a `trainControl` function call that would fulfill the criterion above. I am aware about the ability to call `train()` with the argument `metric = "ROC"`, but I don't really feel that that would do the trick.

It should be stressed, though, that I'm not interested in the underpinnings of any particular model; I could just as well use a GBM, a Neural Network or any other kind of classifier to do the heavy work. I'm just interested in finding out how to tell `caret` (or H2O, or Spark, or whatever I can call from R really) to use the "average per-class error" as the optimization metric.

Comment: "average per-class error" is probably not a good metric, search this site for proper score function, and for logistic model choice.  For instance see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95250/logistic-regression-maximum-likelihood-vs-misclassification/103893#103893

Answer (score 1):

"Average per-class error is usually not a good metric.  For instance, it is not a continuous function of model parameters, so is difficult to optimize. There is also more statistical reasons, it is not a proper score function. Search this site for "proper score function":  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=proper+score+function  For other reasons why it is not a good idea, see [Logistic regression: maximum likelihood vs misclassification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95250/logistic-regression-maximum-likelihood-vs-misclassification/103893#103893)

In most cases, it is more informative to see a problem with a binary variable response as risk (that is, probability) estimation, not as classification. For discussion see [Logistic regression: maximum likelihood vs misclassification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95250/logistic-regression-maximum-likelihood-vs-misclassification/103893#103893)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just looking for the accuracy measure, which is the number of correctly classified instances divided by the total number of instances. For balanced classes (50% class 1, 50% class 2), this is equivalent to the mean of the accuracy within each class. For imbalanced classes (e.g., 90% class 1, 10% class 2), total accuracy is usually a poor measure to optimize on, because even a naive "classifier" can perform quite well by just predicting the majority class for every instance.

Comment: The issues with accuracy run deeper than class balance.

Answer (score 0):

**Mean Per Class Error (in Multi-class Classification only) is the average of the errors of each class in your multi-class data set. This metric speaks toward mis-classification of the data across the classes. The lower this metric, the better.**

But the problem over here is - in case if you are trying to reduce this error in imbalanced data then it leads to more prediction in the majority classes. And the overall model performance will be bad.