# Average of Precision and True negative rate as an accuracy metric

Tags: classification, accuracy, sensitivity-specificity, precision

When attempting to construct a classifier for a somewhat imbalanced data set, I was led to the question of measuring the performance of the classifier. One of the first things I thought of was to take the average of precision and specificity:

$$\frac{(\text{true positive rate} + \text{true negative rate)}}{2}$$

It seems quite an intuitive measure to me. Moreover one can take a weighted average depending on how important the prediction rate for each class is. Also it generalizes in a straightforward way to multiple classes. One can incorporate it into a 2-class cost matrix by setting the off diagonals to:

$$\frac{(N-N_1)}{N}, \frac{(N-N_2)}{N}$$

However, I could not find any reference online to any such measure - there appears to be no name for it! There are all sorts of combinations of other measures, but not this one. I was wondering if someone can point me to any discussion of it.

Edit: I originally had misunderstood the definition of specificity as $TN \over TN+FN$ when actually it is defined as $TN \over TN+FP $. I have corrected the title. As far as I can find, there is no name for "true-negative rate".

Comment: TN/(TN+FN) is the Negative Predictive Value (~"negative precision"). TN/(TN+FP) _is_ specificity. And it _is_ "true negative rate" (or ~"negative recall").

Answer (score 2):

What you are proposing is the *(weighted or not) [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of precision and specificity*.

Two of the most common (confusion matrix) metrics being used are:

- [F1-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score). This is essentially the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of *precision* and *recall*.
- [Fβ-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score#Formulation). A weighted version of the above. It measures the effectiveness of retrieval with respect to a user who attaches β times as much importance to recall as precision.
- [Geometric Mean Score](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.metrics.geometric_mean_score.html). It corresponds to the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) of sensitivity and specificity and is used mostly in imbalanced problems.

Your question essentially comes down to:

> Why are the **harmonic** and **geometric** means preferred to the **arithmetic** mean for averaging confusion matrix metrics?

An excellent answer concerning these three means and their diffenences can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/When-is-it-most-appropriate-to-take-the-arithmetic-mean-vs-geometric-mean-vs-harmonic-mean). Also, a discussion on which mean to use and when can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/which-mean-to-use-and-when).

Comment: Thanks for the information. 

According to the answer at [this link][1]  the average of the per class accuracy is not a "proper score function" - but I'm not convinced. I have to read up on some of the classification terminology and get back.


  [1]: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251970/optimize-a-classification-algorithm-using-mean-per-class-accuracy?rq=1

Comment: Nothing mentioned above is a proper accuracy score.  And are you certain it was appropriate to cast this problem as a classification problem and not one of risk estimation?  Describe the problem more fully.  And note that imbalance is to be expected, so it's not clear why you mentioned that.